# Subject and Phone won't come up when the email is sent

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working on a one page website and it has two different forms that can be filled out. When I fill out one of the forms I receive an email but it doesn't have the phone number (for one of the forms). My second form I can't get the subject to be the subject of the email and include the name in the $headers.
Instead of putting two forms up I assume it would be the same fix for both. I am also using recaptcha and its not working but I will submit that in a different question.

Form 1

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
    <div class="leftSide">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="true" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="true" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" required="true" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>
    <div class="rightSide">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="true" placeholder="Message"></textarea> 
    </div>          
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" id="contactBtn">
</form>
```

post.php form the first form

```
        <?php

    // Clean up the input values
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
      if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
        $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]);

      $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
    }

    // Assign the input values to variables for easy reference
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    // Test input values for errors
    $errors = array();
    if(strlen($name) < 2) {
      if(!$name) {
        $errors[] = "You must enter a name.";
      } else {
        $errors[] = "Name must be at least 2 characters.";
      }
    }
    if(!$email) {
      $errors[] = "You must enter an email.";
    } else if(!validEmail($email)) {
      $errors[] = "You must enter a valid email.";
    }
    if(strlen(!$subject) < 5) {
      $errors[] = "You must enter a subject.";
    } else {
      $errors[] = "You must enter a subject.";
    }
    if(strlen($message) < 10) {
      if(!$message) {
        $errors[] = "You must enter a message.";
      } else {
        $errors[] = "Message must be at least 10 characters.";
      }
    }

    if($errors) {
      // Output errors and die with a failure message
      $errortext = "";
      foreach($errors as $error) {
        $errortext .= "<li>".$error."</li>";
      }
      die("<span class='failure'>The following errors occured:<ul>". $errortext ."</ul></span>");
    }

    // Send the email
    $to = "kevinwernicke@kevinwernicke.com";
    $subject = "$subject";
    $message = "$message";
    $headers = "From: $name" + " $email";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    // Die with a success message
    header("Location: ../index.html");

    // A function that checks to see if
    // an email is valid
    function validEmail($email)
    {
       $isValid = true;
       $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
       if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
       {
          $isValid = false;
       }
       else
       {
          $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
          $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
          $localLen = strlen($local);
          $domainLen = strlen($domain);
          if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
          {
             // local part length exceeded
             $isValid = false;
          }
          else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
          {
             // domain part length exceeded
             $isValid = false;
          }
          else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
          {
             // local part starts or ends with '.'
             $isValid = false;
          }
          else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
          {
             // local part has two consecutive dots
             $isValid = false;
          }
          else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
          {
             // character not valid in domain part
             $isValid = false;
          }
          else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
          {
             // domain part has two consecutive dots
             $isValid = false;
          }
          else if(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
                     str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
          {
             // character not valid in local part unless
             // local part is quoted
             if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
                 str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
             {
                $isValid = false;
             }
          }
          if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
          {
             // domain not found in DNS
             $isValid = false;
          }
       }
       return $isValid;
    }

    ?>
```

Form 2

```
    <form action="post1.php" method="post">
            <h6>SUBMIT YOUR APPEAL REQUEST</h6>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="true" placeholder="First & Last Name">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="true" placeholder="Email Address">
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" required="true" placeholder="Phone Number">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" required="true" placeholder="Details of your claim"></textarea> 

            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT APPEAL REQUEST" id="submitBtn">
        </form>
```

post1.php for the second form

```
<?php

// Clean up the input values
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
    $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]);

  $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
}

// Assign the input values to variables for easy reference
$name = $_POST["name"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];


// Test input values for errors
$errors = array();
if(strlen($name) < 2) {
  if(!$name) {
    $errors[] = "You must enter a name.";
  } else {
    $errors[] = "Name must be at least 2 characters.";
  }
}
if(!$email) {
  $errors[] = "You must enter an email.";
} else if(!validEmail($email)) {
  $errors[] = "You must enter a valid email.";
}
if(!$phone) {
  $errors[] = "You must enter a phone number.";
} else {
  $errors[] = "You must enter a phone number.";
}
if(strlen($message) < 10) {
  if(!$message) {
    $errors[] = "You must enter a message.";
  } else {
    $errors[] = "Message must be at least 10 characters.";
  }
}

if($errors) {
  // Output errors and die with a failure message
  $errortext = "";
  foreach($errors as $error) {
    $errortext .= "<li>".$error."</li>";
  }
  die("<span class='failure'>The following errors occured:<ul>". $errortext ."</ul></span>");
}

// Send the email
$to = "kevinwernicke@kevinwernicke.com";
$subject = "Contact Form: $name";
$message = "$message";
$headers = "From: $email";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// Die with a success message
header("Location: ../index.php");

// A function that checks to see if
// an email is valid
function validEmail($email)
{
   $isValid = true;
   $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
   if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
   {
      $isValid = false;
   }
   else
   {
      $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
      $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
      $localLen = strlen($local);
      $domainLen = strlen($domain);
      if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
      {
         // local part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
      {
         // domain part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
      {
         // local part starts or ends with '.'
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
      {
         // local part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
      {
         // character not valid in domain part
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
      {
         // domain part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
                 str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
      {
         // character not valid in local part unless
         // local part is quoted
         if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
             str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
         {
            $isValid = false;
         }
      }
      if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
      {
         // domain not found in DNS
         $isValid = false;
      }
   }
   return $isValid;
}

?>
```

Comment: phone, what phone? 2nd form, yeah well.. you have that, not us. You're expecting that other one to magically appear? That won't happen. Plus, I'll bet you're using JS; the id's suggest it.

Comment: Why are you using `htmlspecialchars()`? Your email is not HTML.

Comment: `$subject = "$subject";` What's the point of assigning a variable to itself?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this section :

```
if(strlen(!$subject) < 5) {
  $errors[] = "You must enter a subject.";
} else {
  $errors[] = "You must enter a subject.";
}
```

to:

```
if(strlen($subject) < 5) {
  $errors[] = "Subject must be at least 5 characters.";
} elseif(!$subject) {
  $errors[] = "You must enter a subject.";
}
```

Comment: I still keep running into the error of you need to enter a subject.